# How to place one imageview over another?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

i want to place one `imageview` over another. The `imageview` which i want to place above is getting placed below.

Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberofuploads; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            relativeframe1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramslayout1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT / 2,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            paramslayout1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            relativeframe1.setLayoutParams(paramslayout1);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    pxrparams1a, pxrparams1b);

            imgvwphoto1 = new ImageView(this);
            imgvwphoto1.setId(1);
            imgvwphoto1.setAlpha(500);
            imgvwphoto1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plusicon3);
            // params1.setMargins(0, 90, 100, 40);

            params1.setMargins(left1, top1, right1, bottom1);
            imgvwphoto1.setLayoutParams(params1);               
            relativeframe1.addView(imgvwphoto1);
            imgvwphoto1.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            imgvwphoto1.setOnTouchListener(this);               
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramscomponent1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    irpc1, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);               
            paramscomponent1.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

imgvwcomponent1 = new ImageView(this);
imgvwcomponent1.setAlpha(0);
imgvwcomponent1                     .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.leftpartdoubleheartframe);
imgvwcomponent1.setBackgroundResource(componentname.getImagename());
imgvwcomponent1.setLayoutParams(paramscomponent1);

            relativeframe1.addView(imgvwcomponent1);

            relativeframe.addView(relativeframe1);

        } else {
            relativeframe2 = new RelativeLayout(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramslayout2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT / 2,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            paramslayout2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            relativeframe1.setLayoutParams(paramslayout2);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    pxrparams2a, pxrparams2b);// 106.67dp, 120dp
            imgvwphoto2 = new ImageView(this);
            imgvwphoto2.setId(2);
            imgvwphoto2.setAlpha(500);
            imgvwphoto2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.plusicon3);

            // params2.setMargins(165, 90, 0, 40);
            params2.setMargins(left2, top2, right2, bottom2);
            imgvwphoto2.setLayoutParams(params2);
            relativeframe2.addView(imgvwphoto2);
            imgvwphoto2.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

            imgvwphoto2.setOnTouchListener(this);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramscomponent2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    irpc2, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);// 103.33dp

            paramscomponent2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

            imgvwcomponent2 = new ImageView(this);
            imgvwcomponent2.setAlpha(500);
            imgvwcomponent2
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rightpartdoubleheartframe);
            imgvwcomponent2.setLayoutParams(paramscomponent2);

            relativeframe2.addView(imgvwcomponent2);

            relativeframe.addView(relativeframe2);

        }
    }
```

on click of plus icon, image is uploaded on that imgvwphoto,that is overlaping with heart frame, i want it to be viewed inside heart frame only. not outside of heart frame.

Comment: why? why do you want. two ImageViews overlap?

Comment: use framelayout rather relative

Comment: two imageviews for two photo uploads...

Comment: i want to display two imageviews(for photo upload) side by side and two imageviews over those two imageviews for photo frames.all is displaying properly but after uploading photos, the photo imageviews are coming over imageviews for frame. i am not getting how to bring that frame imageview over photo imageview.

Answer (score 0):

You should use two separate layouts and place one at another using `<include>` statemant like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/lay1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


    <include layout="@layout/lay2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</merge>
```